# Hiding secrets when printing debug commands in Python

Tags: python

I am calling an external utility from Python (Vertica `vsql` database cli).
I want to debug-print the commands, but conceal the password from the command print (for security reasons).

I.e. if the command is:

```
 vsql -w mypassword -c "SELECT 1"
```

I will want to print:

```
 vsql -w **** -c "SELECT 1"
```

or similar.

And ideas on an elegant solution?

Comment: One option would be to pass secrets in through env variables if that's an option for Vertica.

Comment: Great idea! I completely forgot about it. Yes, it has the `VSQL_PASSWORD`. @KyleParsons, do you want to paste it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Another elegant implementation is to use an environment variable recognized by the database CLI tool.
In Vertica's case the variable's name is `VSQL_PASSWORD`.

So, if I run

```
export VSQL_PASSWORD=blablapassword
python ./myapp.py
```

Subprocess command in `myapps.py` gets this environment variable and I can avoid using the password in the vsql command.

Thanks to @KyleParsons for reminding of that option!

Answer (score 0):

One elegant way would be via Regex.
Given the structure of this particular command, I can deterministically search-replace the password:

```
def obfuscate_vsql_password(cmd):
    return cmd.startswith("vsql -w") then re.sub('^vsql -w (\S+)', 'vsql -w ******', x) else cmd

def run_cmd(command):
    print("COMMAND: "+ obfuscate_vsql_password(command))
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).decode('UTF-8')
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your commands as strings, e.g.:

```
cmd='vsql -w {{pass}} -c "SELECT 1\"'
```

and when it's time to make the command, format-in the password:

```
... cmd.format(pass=mypassword_var) ...
```

so when you `print(cmd)` only the placeholder comes out

Comment: Did you mean to put just one level of curly brackets? I believe that format won't run due to two levels.